# Is it possible to place div 100px lower?

Tags: html, css

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="content">
    <div class="centralPanel">
        <div class="panel leftPanel">
            <div class="widget home" id="home">home</div>
            <div class="widget" id="topServices">top</div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel rightPanel">
            <div class="widget home" id="userArea">user</div>
            <div class="widget" id="newServices">new</div>
        </div>
                <div id="searchResult" class="mainText">result<br/>result<br/>result<br/>result<br/>result<br/>result<br/>result<br/>result<br/>result<br/>result<br/>result<br/>result<br/></div>
    <div class="bottomPanel" id="bottomPanel">bottom</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.content {
    margin-top: 80px;
    width: 100%;
}

div.panel {
    position: absolute;
    height: 500px;
    width: 200px;
    top: 0;
}

div.leftPanel {
    left: 0;
}

div.centralPanel {
    width: 752px;
    min-height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

div.bottomPanel {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 752px;
}

div.rightPanel {
    right: 0;
}

.servicesWidget {
    color: #149bdf;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 275px;
    width: 145px !important;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 1px solid #149bdf;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.servicesWidgetCell {
    border-top: 1px solid #149bdf;
}

.topDiv {
    height: 23px;
}

.mainText {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/d5e8n4d1/4/)

If "result" has too much data, "bottom" must be positioned after "result", but, if "result" hasn't much information then "bottom" must be 100px lower.

Is it possible via HTML and CSS?

Comment: You should describe your actual css problem in a more clear way, eg. what does 'too much data' mean?
Moreover, your jsfiddle link is not clickable.

Comment: Please clarify your question.  Its not clear what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want move a Div (I presume?) 100px lower you can easily do it like this:

```
margin-top: 100px;
```

Comment: margin-top makes ot lower too if there are to much data in "result". I want to place it lower only if there is no text or text is short in "result".

Comment: then add a margin-bottom to your 'upper'/'header' element